# How can I get rid of the black background on images captured with Robot?

Tags: java, awtrobot

In Button click I have implemented the code, when I click the button first time it will get the x, y postion value, when I click the button the second time it will get the x1,y1 value and capture the image. But somehow it is additionally adding a black background to the original picture. How can I avoid this?

```
Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
c++;
Dimension d = tool.getScreenSize();
if(c==1)
{
    x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; 
    y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
}
if(c==2)
{
    int x1= MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x; 
    int y1= MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,x1,y1);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    String J="Screen";
    J=J+""+i;
    //*************
    String ext = ".jpg";
    String path = loc+J+ ext;
    File f = new File(path);
    i++;
    Thread t1 = new Thread();
    t1.sleep(100);
    BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
    // img.createGraphics();
    ImageIO.write(img,"jpeg",f);
    tool.beep();
    c=0;
    x=0;
    y=0;
    x1=0;
    y1=0;  
}
```

Comment: I partially formatted your code, but could you please take some time to make it look a little neater.

Comment: See my new answer.  I think I found your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in a `mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)` method (in a [`MouseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)), why are you using:

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
```

You should probably be using the methods on [`MouseEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html):

```
event.getX();
```

or

```
event.getXOnScreen();
```

Perhaps the `MouseInfo` methods are giving you incorrect values.

Comment: Button bob = new Button(); bob.addmouseListner(this); i gave like this while click on the button, its giving only button x, y position.

Comment: but i need screen x, y position

Comment: @jcrs, so, you must be implementing the mouse listener in your code, so you do have access to the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: @jcrs, use `event.getXOnScreen();` that will give you the location on the screen.

Comment: hi sorry, i forgot to use getXOnScreen();

Comment: but still, its adding black background in the leftside and bottom

Comment: problem in x * y image i think, when x=y(256*256) working correctly.. when x exceeds y  or wise versa..adding black background

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.  The constructor for [`Rectangle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) takes an `x` and a `y` starting position, and a `height` and a `width`.  It looks like you are giving it 2 x/y points.

Try this instead:

```
int height = Math.max(y - y1, y1 - y);
int width = Math.max(x - x1, x1 - x);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x,y,width, height);
```

Comment: i got d.getwidth(where Dimension d ) and i seperate it by (m=d.getwidth-x1), den i used like Rectangle(x,y,x1-m,) like wise height